# How to send php parameter from one function to other (function.php)?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, google-analytics, contact-form-7

I'm setting up Google Analytics events on Wordpress Contact Form 7. 
How can I send a referrer link to GA javascript code?

I have referrer link on my Contact Form 7 page in a hidden input and send it in an email. But I also need to send the referral link in javascript google analytics code.

For example, ga( 'send', 'event', 'form', 'contact', 'REFERRAL-LINK' );

Here is a part of my **function.php:**

```
// function.php 
function getRefererPage( $form_tag ) {
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && $form_tag['name'] == 'referer- 
   page' ) {
   $form_tag['values'][] = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
  }
  return $form_tag;
}
add_filter( 'wpcf7_form_tag', 'getRefererPage' );


add_action( 'wp_footer', 'mycustom_wp_footer' );
function mycustom_wp_footer() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener('wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
            ga( 'send', 'event', 'form', 'contact', 'REFERRAL-LINK' );
        }, false);
    </script>
<?php
}
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

If you have the referral link in a PHP variable on the page you can echo the variable or the result of a function anywhere into the JS script.

```
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    let referralLink = '<?php echo $referralLink; ?>';
    document.addEventListener('wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
        ga( 'send', 'event', 'form', 'contact', referralLink );
    }, false);
</script>
<?php
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll check it today)